# Creating PDF's using PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation

What I am wanting to do is create a PDF ideally from HTML code. I found a class called [dompdf](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/index.php) but I'm having issues with font and page breaks.

Does anyone know of another script or even a better way in general to generate PDF files?

The reason why I am converting HTML to PDF is because I want someone to use a WYSIWYG editor to create the contents and click save to generate their PDF file...

Any input would be greatly apprecaited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the different nature of PDF and HTML you'll always have to make a few comprimises when trying to convert HTML into PDF.

If this doesn't bother you too much, I'd get started with [TCPDF](http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf). Its easy to use and has a fairly good grasp of colors, sizes and some other style related HTML attributes.

Answer (score 1):

i use this class **TCPDF** :

http://www.tecnick.com/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=tcpdf

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a bit of work then you can use [Cairo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.cairo.php) to generate PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [html2fpdf](http://html2fpdf.sourceforge.net/). It can accept very basic html and css.