# How to create pdf using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, pdf-generation

i want to create PDF file for my PHP  web page it must be some button like create PDF
then user click button PDF file must automatically generate 
my  web page  dynamic page it contain MySQL tables how i do it and there are any open source software for it ...

Comment: You should really post some code to show what you've attempted so far, or use google if you want open source software. This is a site to help people, not to just hand out solutions I'm afraid

Comment: Possible duplicate questin on stackoverflow.com http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620028/creating-pdfs-using-php

Comment: [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) is my personal favourite, there are many other alternatives though, such as [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate the PHP as you usually would but add the `header`

```
header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition:inline; filename="testing.pdf"'); //view in browser
```

Or

```
 header("Content-Type: application/pdf");
 header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="testing.pdf"'); //force download
```

Comment: Anchor, button, whatever. When the browser loads the file it reads the header.

Comment: Have you even tested this? `Content-Type: application/pdf` is not enough to make a PDF. It is enough to *mark* a document as "PDF" so the browser knows what to expect - if you send a normal HTML document afterwards, you'll get an error message. You still need to encode your document as PDF - for example with FPDF (or TCPDF like Dale proposed). What you are doing is like renaming a .FLAC to .MP3 so that your favourite portable player can play it.

Comment: @Pharaoh Nope, I didn't. I just read a few of the related post. I'm not a fan of PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

You can make PDFs with fpdf: http://fpdf.org/

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```